# Summing up values across multiple columns into groups which are defined in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have device data spread across various channels , the channels come in 3 separate groups and are defined by a dictionary.Now from the dataset I need to sum the columns into 3 separate groups as in the dictionary.

**Input** :

```
device_id   class   Channel A   Channel B   Channel C   Channel D   Channel E   Channel F   Channel G   Channel H   Channel I   Channel J
28          S           2           4           23          45          6           6           8           9           0           0
54          P           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
97          S           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
14          V           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
21          P           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
23          V           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
22          P           0           0           32          76          89          0           0           0           0           0
29          P           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
25          S           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
27          P           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
```

So as per the description of the problem the expected output:

**Expected Output**:

```
device_id   S   P   V
28          6   74  23
54          0   0   0
97          0   0   0
14          0   0   0
21          0   0   0
23          0   0   0
22          0   197 0
29          0   0   0
25          0   0   0
27          0   0   0
```

And the dictionary containing the mapping is:

The **dictionary**:

```
{               
'S' : ['Channel A','Channel B'],                
'P' : ['Channel C','Channel D','Channel E'],                
'V' : ['Channel F','Channel G','Channel H','Channel I',' Channel J']
}
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: If your question was answered, don't forget to mark the answer accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, flatten and invert your mapping -

```
m = {j : k for k, v in d.items() for j in v}
m

{'Channel A': 'S',
 'Channel B': 'S',
 'Channel C': 'P',
 'Channel D': 'P',
 'Channel E': 'P',
 'Channel F': 'V',
 'Channel G': 'V',
 'Channel H': 'V',
 'Channel I': 'V',
 'Channel J': 'V'}
```

Now, we'll do the following -

- `set_index` with `device_id`
- get rid of `class` using `drop` (since we don't need it)
- perform a `rename` operation on the column names with the mapping generated earlier
- perform a `groupby` on the identically named columns, summing up the columns

```
df.set_index('device_id')\
  .drop('class', 1)\
  .rename(columns=m)\
  .groupby(axis=1, level=0, sort=False)\
  .sum()

           S    P   V
device_id            
28         6   74  23
54         0    0   0
97         0    0   0
14         0    0   0
21         0    0   0
23         0    0   0
22         0  197   0
29         0    0   0
25         0    0   0
27         0    0   0
```